# SQL and POST requests

Tags: php, sql

How do I handle variables from POST requests? Lets say I have tables like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V5gk.png) And I want to update the votes variable wherever a specific id is.

So for the code I have this

```
$vote = $_POST["votes"];
$sentid = $_POST["sentid"];
```

along with something like this

```
UPDATE `my_exampleo202s`.`President Candidates` SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE `President Candidates`.`id` = sentid
```

And in the post request I send the sentid with a number. sentid=3

This doesn't work though. I'm not able to give any errors or anything because I'm not viewing it from a browser.

Any idea what the proper way is that I'm supposed to do this?

(Here's the code I have right now if it's needed)

```
<?php
    $vote = $_POST["votes"];
    $sentid = $_POST["sentid"];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","exampleo202s","","my_exampleo202s");


    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "UPDATE `my_exampleo202s`.`President Candidates` SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE `President Candidates`.`id` = sentid";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<br>Record updated successfully <br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Error updating record: <br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

UPDATE

```
<?php
    $vote = $_POST["votes"];
    $sentid = $_POST["sentid"];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","jusavoting10rxx9s3","","my_jusavoting10rxx9s3");


    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "UPDATE `my_jusavoting10rxx9s3`.`President Candidates` SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE `President Candidates`.`id` = $sentid";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<br>Record updated successfully <br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Error updating record: <br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `\`my_exampleo202s\`.\`President Candidates\`` doesn't look like a proper table name. What does your database look like? And regardless if you use a browser or not, you can still log the `$conn->error` to an external file.

Comment: You should be using [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: In your query it should be $sentid

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I didn't use my actual table name for this, it's worked perfectly fine before so I don't think that's the problem, but I may be wrong. Didn't know I could log that to an external file, interesting

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma I just tried that, still not updating

Comment: @Sploit - Maybe you should post your actual code so we could review it? :) it's hard to debug a pseudo code.

Comment: your post value must be blank then, try setting it $sentid = 1 and check. can you post rest of your code because I am sure this code is correct.

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma There, sorry, I was getting the comments confused and didn't realize you already suggested I post the rest of the code. It's up there now.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo your $_POST value if it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $vote = $_POST["votes"];
    $sentid = $_POST["sentid"];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","exampleo202s","","my_exampleo202s");


    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "UPDATE `my_exampleo202s`.`President Candidates` SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE `President Candidates`.`id` = $sentid";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<br>Record updated successfully <br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Error updating record: <br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: The only problem is that I'm not viewing it from a browser, so I'm not able to see the results

Comment: what you mean? is your database table updating?

Comment: yeah it's not updating. I can update the original question with the exact code I have if you want, not sure if it'll help though

Comment: are you sure you getting value in $sentid? did you try hard code by replacing $sentid = $_POST['sentid']; to $sentid = 3; ?

Comment: Alright, I just tried using $sentid = 3; and that worked. Am I not declaring the variable right when I do $sentid = $_POST["sentid"]

Comment: As I said your post value is blank. How you are sending values?

Comment: Well, right now I'm sending the values with lua, sometimes I test with fiddler though. So I have ' PostAsync("http://examplesite/PresCand.php" , "sentid=3", 2) '  And in fiddler I have POST, http://examplesite/PresCand.php, HTTP/1.1, and the request body is sentid=3. I'm really sorry if I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be, I'm really new to this.